# Getting null for optJSONArray

Tags: java, json

So I have the line:

```
JSONObject res = new JSONObject(result);
```

The output of this is:

```
{
  "result": "[\"Pretty Woman\",\"Minions Banana Song\",\"Squatters Rights\",\"Minions Banana\",\"Minions Puppy\"]",
  "id": 0,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

Then I have the line:

```
JSONArray moviesJson = res.optJSONArray("result");
```

and the output of that is null. Is this a syntax error on my part? I can't figure out what's going on.

I'm trying to get the array contained in result as my output

Comment: Why don't you try putting your JSON into an online JSOn viewer and check if it is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key `result` contains an array but in the form of single string. You can get the array as:

```
JSONArray moviesJson = new JSONArray(res.getString("result"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`"result"` does not contain a JSON array, it's a String representation of an array.

Remove the surrounding double-quotes and the backslashes.

Change:

```
{
  "result": "[\"Pretty Woman\",\"Minions Banana Song\",\"Squatters Rights\",\"Minions Banana\",\"Minions Puppy\"]",
  "id": 0,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

to

```
{
  "result": [
    "Pretty Woman",
    "Minions Banana Song",
    "Squatters Rights",
    "Minions Banana",
    "Minions Puppy"
  ],
  "id": 0,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

Comment: How do I get an array, then?

Answer (score 1):

JSON Array will be like

```
{
  "result": ["Pretty Woman","Minions Banana Song","Squatters Rights","Minions Banana","Minions Puppy"],
  "id": 0,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

You are considering it as an string of a JSON Object.Which should obliviously 
show null value.

To get an JSON array value ,

```
JSONarray result= somejsonobjectname.getJSONArray("Result")
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Your overall output at present is also an Object:

```
{"result":"[\"Pretty Woman\",\"Minions Banana Song\",\"Squatters
Rights\",\"Minions Banana\",\"Minions Puppy\"]","id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

A corresponding sample for this would be:

```
class Sample {
    String result;
    String id;
    String jsonrpc;
    ...getters and setters
}
```

You shall try to parse into a `JSONObject` first and then subsequently pull out the array of `results`.